# REST API Routes with Sinatra not working

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to create a simple Sinatra app that pulls a slew of postal codes from the database and render it in JSON. I have two get statements right now

```
get '/postalcodes' do    
    PostalCodes.all.to_json only: [:CountryCode, :PostalCode, :PlaceName, :AdminName1, :AdminCode1, :AdminName2, :AdminCode2, :AdminName3, :AdminCode3, :Latitude, :Longitude, :Accuracy]   
end

get '/postalcodes/:countrycode' do    
    PostalCodes.find(params[:countrycode]).to_json only: [:CountryCode, :PostalCode, :PlaceName, :AdminName1, :AdminCode1, :AdminName2, :AdminCode2, :AdminName3, :AdminCode3, :Latitude, :Longitude, :Accuracy]   
end
```

The first GET works fine but I would expect that I could enter the URI:

```
localhost:3000/postalcodes/US
```

to get all the postal codes with the country code of 'US'. Well, it's not working.

Comment: Ruby convention for column names is snake case, and singular for the models, just FYI. For your problematic query, you would want to do `PostalCodes.where(CountryCode: params[:countrycode])` to retrieve the records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `activerecord` handling the database for `PostalCodes`, you would do it like so:

```
PostalCodes.where("CountryCode" => params[:countrycode].to_s).all
```

I made further assumptions about column names in your database, so I hope the basic idea comes across even if the specific code might not work.